# Page Footer Page X of Y

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following vba codes

```
    Sub pageNumber(objOutputDoc As Object)

'    With objOutputDoc.Sections(objOutputDoc.Sections.Count)
'        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = vbTab & vbTab & "Page "
'        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add FirstPage:=True
'    End With
    Dim i As Long, bAdd As Boolean: bAdd = True
    With objOutputDoc.Sections(objOutputDoc.Sections.Count).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range 'First.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
      For i = 1 To .Fields.Count
        If .Fields(i).Type = wdFieldPage Then
          bAdd = False: Exit For
        End If
      Next
      If bAdd = True Then
        .InsertAfter vbTab & vbTab & "Page "
        .Fields.Add .Characters.Last, wdFieldEmpty, "PAGE", False
        .InsertAfter " of "
        .Fields.Add .Characters.Last, wdFieldEmpty, "NUMPAGES", False
      End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The above vba codes automatically add Page X of Y to my word documents. My word document contains for example 27 pages so when i run my vba the pages numbers are inserted Page of 1 of 27 ,Page 2 of 27 and so on.I am having an issue my last page that is page 27 , i have already inserted at the bottom of the last page  Page 1 of 1..when i run vba , page 27 of 27 is inserted on the last page now  i am having page 1 of 1 and page 27 of 27. I want the penultimate page to be Page 26 of 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided pages 1 to 26 are in the same section you can achieve your goal by using `SECTIONPAGES` instead of `NUMPAGES`.

Then for the following section you need to restart the page numbering:

```
With objOutputDoc.Sections(objOutputDoc.Sections.Count).HeaderFooter.PageNumbers
    .RestartNumberingAtSection = True
    .StartingNumber = 1
End With
```